# 'InvalidContainerGroupUpdate' when using 'create group container' in logic apps azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have been looking into the "logic apps designer' of Microsoft azure for a couple of days. Thank you for your help!  I am stuck on the following:

**Context**
I wanted to perform some actions interacting between multiple files in a Dropbox. The logic app was not proposing an off-the-self solution, hence I created a python script that did exactly what I wanted.

I then decided to create an image of this script in order to be able to use it from the azure platform within the Logic Apps.

The containers registry contains the image I pushed to Azure and I created the container instance that includes only one image which is the python script.

Everything works.

**Current structure**
From what I read, it seems that we can run the container instance by using the action called `create group container` then adding a `until` action (*run until state is equal to Succeeded*) and finally using `delete the container group`.

I have a trigger that has been tested and that works.

**Issue**
When running the Logic App, the action `create group container` is failing:

```
"code": "InaccessibleImage",
"message": "The image '<name_of_the_image>' in container group '<name_of_the_group>' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."
```

**Question**
How can I correct what seems to be a basic error on my part?
Where can this registry credential be appropriately corrected?

**Update**
I have tried removing everything, assigning myself "owner" role in the container registry, then adding the container instance, assigning myself "owner" role in the container instance, then rebuilt the logic app. I ran it again and I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured the issue.

Since in my case, it is a private container registry, I needed to add the following the the action 'create group container': **properties.imageRegistryCredentials**.
In this, you will be required to enter the following information that are available in the Access keys of the container registry:

```
[
  {
    "password": "<yourpassword>",
    "server": "<yourloginserver>",
    "username": "<yourusername>"
  }
]
```

So glad and I hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

To set the credentials of **ACI** inside **Create or update container group** task in **logic app** you need to add a parameter (See the picture).

[add parameter for ACI credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fviwp.jpg)